# What can one gain from learning language constructed for books or films, like Sindarin?

Tags: language-acquisition, constructed-language, dead-languages

I know about people who learn, use and even develop the constructed languages created for books or films, such as Sindarin.

Most of them are doing it because of a very geek interest in the topic, or to simply do something different. But I'm wondering if there may be more linguistic rationale behind it, such as:

1. Learning language with original structure, which is a kind of mind exercise
2. Beeing a part of language that is created gives the ability to observe the process of language evolution
3. The need to invent new words is also challenging

But, wouldn't a person profit more from learning one of more exotic existing languages (Inuit) or dead languages (Sumerian, Nahuatl)?

Comment: There are different people who *learn* and who *develop* them. Aside from developing a language for a book, what else could be a reason to develop a language if you are not Ben-Yehuda? :-)

Comment: Not a high quality question. You're asking if there is any moral merit to what some see as a hobby, some see it as fraud and pseudo-science, some see as a job (well for at least two or three working linguists, like Paul Frommer), and some see as a serious project with a variety of applications- applied and theoretical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learning any new language helps open your mind to the very different ways in which languages can work. This is always a good thing and will stay with you.

If you are not motivated to learn a foreign language but are motivated to learn a "constructed" language like Esperanto, or a "fictional" language like Klingon, your mind will still be opened to some of the possible variation in language.

Later on when you are motivated to learn a foreign language, the fact that you have already opened your mind by studying a made-up language will reduce some of the barriers. Because while you still lack experience in say French, you do have experience in producing sounds and forming and parsing morphosyntactical structures quite different from your native language.

Think of it as "what is the point of pure science?" You never know when a practical application pure knowledge will be beneficial *at some point in the future*.

I bet if I had learned Klingon as a kid that the strange and wonderful language features Georgian is throwing at me today would be at least a little bit easier to grok. After all Klingon was specifically devised, by a real linguist, to be very different at most levels to English and other common Western European languages.

Answer (score 3):

Knowledge of a language identifies one with a constituency speaking that language. Immigrants to a new place can usually gain more than a modicum of acceptance in the host community if they are able to speak the host language fluently. Someone might feel more at home within the community of Star Trek enthusiasts than, say, the community of Inuits. I am also quite confident that the average person will receive more encouragement from the Star Trek enthusiast community than from the community of Inuit speakers if they are taking up a new language spoken by that community.

Comment: If you move in to some Inuit community to learn their language, I suppose you will receive quite some encouragement, too.

Comment: the Inuit case is hypothetical, since I don't know anything about Inuit attitudes towards their language w/r/t to non-Inuit learning it, but there are clear cases of societies where foreigners are discouraged from learning. In the first half of the 19th century, for example, it was forbidden for Chinese people to teach a Westerner Chinese, or for a Westerner to learn Chinese.